# MySQL Decimal Returning As Int

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print a value from MySQL database; the value is of type decimal(1,2). When I print it with PHP 5.2, it displays it as an int.

Here is the table:

> Script|Version
>
> 1|1.5
>
> 2|2.0

Here is my function:

```
function getVersion($script)
{
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Version FROM Scripts WHERE Script = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $script);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($version);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        printf("\"%d\"", $version);
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

I assumed it would print as a decimal since the format I chose is a decimal; am I not seeing something? I tried using number_format, but that didn't help.

Comment: You will always get an integer when you print using `%d`. Have you done anything else to verify that it's actually an `int`?

Answer (score 3):

The 'd' of the `%d` format stands for "decimal" as in "base 10", not as in "number with a fractional part".  If you want the fraction displayed, use `%f` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("\"%1\$.2f\"", $version);
```

so that the decimal(1,2) is enforced, since just `%f` will show the max decimals in a float, which on my platform is 6.

Comment: I tried "\"%1\$.2f\"", but it didn't work out as expected. I proceeded to use "\"%2.1f\"" and this worked for me.

Comment: weird, both mine and your solution are working for me. glad you got where you were going